# Is there a privacy field or a way to set privacy for Facebook API Questions/Polls object?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

When using the Graph API to post questions/Polls, is it possible to set privacy fields to limit who sees the question? (example: in the post object you can set who sees the post by setting privacy value: 'CUSTOM', friends:'SOME_FRIENDS', allow:'User_Id')  If there isn't a similar feature for posting questions yet, does anyone know if or when it may be added?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment. It would make a nice feature request though.